# python regex on variable

Tags: python, regex

Please help with my regex problem

Here is my string

```
source="http://www.amazon.com/ref=s9_hps_bw_g200_t2?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_i=3421"
source_resource="pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER"
```

The `source_resource` is in the `source` may end with `&` or with `.`[for example].

So far,

```
regex = re.compile("pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER+[&.]")
regex.findall(source)
[u'pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&']
```

I have used the text here. Rather using text, how can i use `source_resource` variable with `&` or `.` to find this out.

Comment: I think i found out. Let me wait for other experts to give their idea
`pattern=re.compile( source_resource+'[&.]')`

Comment: Yes that is (nearly) correct - just escape the `.` with a `\ `, because in regular-expressions a normal dot will match on `any` character, not just a dot.

Comment: @Sathy Does `source_resource` stay the same throughout the program?

Comment: @Jared it goes under a `if-elif-else` module which creates different `source_resource` against each condition satisfied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to escape the `.`

```
pattern=re.compile(source_resource + '[&\.]')
```

Answer (score 3):

*If* the goal is to extract the `pf_rd_m` value (which it apparently is as you are using `regex.findall`), than I'm not sure regex are the easiest solution here:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> qs = urlparse.urlparse(source).query
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(qs)
{'pf_rd_m': ['ATVPDKIKX0DER'], 'pf_rd_i': ['3421']}
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(qs)['pf_rd_m']
['ATVPDKIKX0DER']
```

Comment: thanks @icecrime. this is what I have done since my thought is `pf_rd_m` might change in future. `source_resource=source.split('?')[1].split('&')[0]` I always want the first value of my query, no matter what is assigned. Advise me if any better option

Answer (score 1):

You can just build the string for the regular expression like a normal string, utilizing all string-formatting options available in Python:

```
import re
source_and="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0030DI8NA/pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&"
source_dot="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0030DI8NA/pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER."
source_resource="pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER"
regex_string = source_resource + "[&\.]"
regex = re.compile(regex_string)
print regex.findall(source_and)
print regex.findall(source_dot)
>>> ['pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&']
['pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER.']
```

I hope this is what you mean.

Just take note that I modified your regular expression: the `.` is a special symbol and needs to be escaped, as is the `+` (I just assumed the string will only occur once, which makes the use of + unnecessary).